# appending & to unrecognized command closes terminal tab

Tags: linux-mint, terminal

I know about the use of `&` to background commands. But when I try to use it with an unrecognized command, for example entering `a &` into the terminal and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it closes the terminal tab. Why is this? I'm using Linux Mint 18.

Comment: What shell are you using and what terminal emulator?

Comment: How can I find that information? I'm just using the default Linux Mint terminal

Comment: For the first part, type `echo $TERM` . For the 2nd, I'm gonna have to guess that it's gnome-terminal (not familiar with Mint though).

Comment: Typing `echo $TERM` outputs `xterm-256color`. And yeah, I looked into it and it's GNOME Terminal 3.18.3

Comment: My bad, it was `echo $SHELL`, not `echo $TERM`

Comment: oh okay, it's `/bin/bash`

Comment: I just tried what you said with gnome-terminal 3.18.3 and bash on Ubuntu, and, as expected, it says "Command not found".

Comment: I don't suppose you set up any traps on `ERR`? `trap -p` would confirm or deny the idea.

Comment: the output when I enter that is `trap -- '' SIGTSTP`, `trap -- '' SIGTTIN`, and `trap -- '' SIGTTOU`. Not sure how to interpret this

Comment: It doesn't appear you have any traps that would cause the shell to exit with the unknown command. Does this happen with any unknown command or is `a` the only one you have tried? The thought would be that something might be sending an exit signal like a `ctrl-d` to the shell/terminal.

Comment: It happens with any unknown command. Is there any way to see what's going on "under the surface" in the terminal? Like log files?